# query select data with any character not a-z|0-9|#|space

Tags: mysql

I want to run a mysql query where I get all data from rows where one of the characters is not one of the following: a-z, 0-9, #, [space]. I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Mysql, You should find the answer here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

try something like :

`select * from table 
where field_name NOT REGEXP '[a-z]|[0-9]|[:space:]';`

Should work, good luck !

Comment: This should works similarly `WHERE YourColumn REGEXP '[^a-z0-9# ]'`